# Is there an API or way to push updated data to all users live if one live user changes or updates one column of data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, datatable

We are using spring as back end process, hibernate as dao layer and maven as build tool for the project and data tables as the front end data display as a dashboard. Dashboard has almost 30 columns and 25 of them are editable by selected users who has admin rights.

Let say 5 users are viewing the Dashboard at the same time and one user change the data in some column then how we push updated data to other 4 users who are viewing same data live. In other words, how we push updated or changed data to all other live users if one live user changes something.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [Websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [server side event](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp).

You can also implement your own mechanism. Create an URL endpoint where javascript clients connect regulary to check for updates. The idea is to have a service exposing updates to clients each time a data is updated in the database.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the difference between JMS, websocket or server side event??

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Spring 4, Spring now supports WebSockets and actually make them easy to use. To get your hands dirty check out [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) tutorial.

An older solution that is fairly common is [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).